# Get the link of a page loaded inside a <div> container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My jQuery code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    //load the index page into a div container

    //set a bottom (border) line under the item of navigation bar

    $('#siteloader').load('empleados.jsp');   
    $('ul#menu li a.active').css({"borderbottom": "4px solid"});


    //When the hyperlink is clicked
    // set the right color to the item of the navigation bar

    $('ul#menu li a').click(function() {
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        if (page !== 'index.jsp') {
            $('#siteloader').load(page + '.jsp');
            $('ul#menu li a').css({"color": "#000"});
            $(this).css({"color": "#ca4b00"});
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });

    //set the color to the item in which the mouse is hovering ontop   
    // a bottom (border) line go to the item where i'm hover

    $('ul#menu li a').hover(function() {
        $('ul#menu li a').css({"color": "#000"});
        $('ul#menu li a').css({"border-bottom-style": "none"});
        $(this).css({"color": "#ca4b00"});
        $(this).css({"border-bottom": "4px solid"});
    });

});
```

The **problem** with this code is that if I don't click at an item , the color and the bottom line are not set to the correct item. What do I need to do in order to have the line and the color set to the right item?

Comment: Try removing the css code from the click event and put it directly in document.ready (that is if you want the color to load when the page loads)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

- add the style using CSS selectors instead of javascript
- define the `hover` and `click` as separate functions and trigger them manually.

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {    //load the index page into a div container

      //set a bottom (border) line under the item of navigation bar

      $('#siteloader').load('empleados.jsp');   
      $('ul#menu li a.active').css({"borderbottom": "4px solid"});


      var onClick = function() {
          var page = $(this).attr('href');
          if (page !== 'index.jsp') {
              $('#siteloader').load(page + '.jsp');
              $('ul#menu li a').css({"color": "#000"});
              $(this).css({"color": "#ca4b00"});
              return false;
          }
          return true;
      };

      var onHover = function() {
          $('ul#menu li a').css({"color": "#000"});
          $('ul#menu li a').css({"border-bottom-style": "none"});
          $(this).css({"color": "#ca4b00"});
          $(this).css({"border-bottom": "4px solid"});
      };

      //When the hyperlink is clicked
      // set the right color to the item of the navigation bar

      $('ul#menu li a').click(onClick);

      //set the color to the item in which the mouse is hovering ontop   
      // a bottom (border) line go to the item where i'm hover

      $('ul#menu li a').hover(onHover);

          var desiredElement =  $('ul#menu li a').eq(0); // the element you want to apply the styles too. Change the `0` value to select other elements.

          onClick.call(desiredElement); //call the function with the desired element as `this`
          onHover.call(desiredElement); //call the function with the desired element as `this`
  });
  ```